# printing summary of results in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I have a python script which makes an http request to an API in order to pull "member" data. It then runs a loop to hit several different member ID's (listed in a text file) to see if each of them are "expired" or not. What I would like to do is print out a summary of these results instead of printing out the individual results for each of the members. Here is my Python script:

```
import requests
import json

qa_members = open("numbers_members.txt")
arraylist = []
    for line in qa_members.readlines():
    arraylist.extend(line.split())
qa_members.close()

arraylist = map(int, arraylist)


authorization_code = raw_input("please enter your authorization code: ")
members = arraylist
print "Member Check Starting"

for member in members:
    url = "http://api22.wiki.com/v1.12/member?id="+str(member)  

    header = {"Authorization": authorization_code}

    response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

    member_check = json.loads(response.text)

    final_member_status = member_check["response"]["member"]
    ["is_expired"]

    print str(member) + " expired status: " + str(final_member_status)


if final_member_status == False:
    print "All Members Passed"
else:
    print "Some members are expired, please refer to log"

print "Member Check Complete"
```

From this, I get several terminal outputs like:

```
123 expired status: False
567 expired status: False
```

Is there way to instead, print out a summary of the results? It could be something like:

```
"24 members returned False"
"11 members returned True"
```

It would also be helpful to find out the ID of a particular member if the status returned was "true":

```
"Member 1234 returned True"
```

Or something similar to that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first thought:

```
falsecount = 0
truecount = 0
for member in members:
    url = "http://api22.wiki.com/v1.12/member?id="+str(member)  

    header = {"Authorization": authorization_code}

    response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

    member_check = json.loads(response.text)

    final_member_status = member_check["response"]["member"]["is_expired"]

    if final_member_status = False:
        falsecount += 1
    else:
        truecount +=1

print str(falsecount) + "members returned False"
print str(truecount) + "members returned False"
```

**EDIT**

I am unable to check however what the output of `final_member_status = member_check["response"]["member"]["is_expired"]` is. This could be `"False"` or `False` (thus, a string or an actual evaluation), if it is `"False"` (a string) then my line should read `if final_member_status = "False"`, however, if it is an evaluation (returning False if the mentioned son field does not exist) the above code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

create a list and append your results to it:

```
results = []

for member in members:
    (...)
    results.append(str(final_member_status))
```

[How can I count the occurrences of a list item in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python)

```
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1].count(1)
3
```

Comment: This option is way slower then creating an int value and simply counting `+1` in each round. However, if you'd like to be able to backtrace the output it is indeed a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two counters outside the for loop and then increase the counters based on `True` or `False`, something like this :

```
# Set both counts to 0 outside the for loop
true_count = 0
false_count = 0

# increment count values based on check inside the for loop
if final_member_status : 
    true_count = true_count + 1
else :
    false_count = false_count + 1

# And finally print outside for loop in the desired format
print("{} members returned True".format(str(true_count)))
print("{} members returned False".format(str(false_count)))
```

This will result the aggregated sum of both checks.